# How can I copy only files with specific string values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to copy files from one folder to another anytime the file contains a certain string using `shutil.copy()`. The 3-digit string values are stored in a list.

If it helps, the 3-digit value will always be at the same position within the file name, and no where else.

File name examples:

```
001_001fds  
032_002fds <--Copy  
234_003ffs <--Copy  
432_004fds <--Copy  
543_005fds
434_006ffs

List = [002, 003, 004]
source = U:\MySourceFolder\Files
source = U:\MyDestinationFolder\Files
for x in list:
    for y in list:
        y = os.listdir(source + y[0])
        print y
        shutil.copy(NetPath + "\\" + x , destination)
```

This is all I have so far. I've tried a few different ways to do wildcards from a list, but I don't think any of them are near right. Any ideas or guidance appreciated.

Comment: Where do these files originate from? Currently your code has a `List` (should use a different variable name) that contains the values which if matched to a file name would be copied. All you're doing above is listing the directory (example `U:\MySourceFolder\Files002`) and printing that.

Comment: Also, why the two `for` loops?